# How to Draw a given Character in exact height?

Tags: c#, graphics

I am drawing the text using Graphics.DrawString() method, But the text height drawn is not same as which i gave.

**For Eg:**

```
Font F=new Font("Arial", 1f,GraphicUnit.Inch);
g.DrawString("M", F,Brushes.red,new Point(0,0));
```

By using the above code, i'm drawing the text with height 1 inch, but the text drawn is not exactly in 1 inch.

I need to Draw the text in Exact height which i'm giving. Thanks in advance..

Comment: What are you measuring it on and how? Your screen? Printed?

Comment: The Text will always leave a little space (leading) above and below. To get the size needed for your aim you should measure it in a loop until you find the best font size. use MeasureString or TextRenderer

Comment: To add to my comment above: The leading is dependent on the Font and the text to measure will determine the returned size, so 'x' , 'X', 'Â' and  'y' will return different heights!

Comment: @ CyberDude And @Taw: Thanks for your response,  i am getting same result in the screen and the print. if i enter the text height as 1 inch, the Character M in the printed should be exactly 1 Inch with out  any above and below the white spaces.

Comment: I have written a solution that shows you how the scale to the right size in a two-step process..

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution will be to use a `GraphicsPath`. Here are the steps necessary:

- Calculate the height you want in pixels: To get 1.0f inches at, say 150 dpi you need 150 pixels.
- Then create a `GraphicsPath` and add the character or string in the font and font style you want to use, using the calculated height
- Now measure the resulting height, using `GetBounds`.
- Then scale the height up to the necessary number of pixels
- Finally clear the path and add the string again with the new height
- Now you can use `FillPath` to output the pixels..

Here is a code example. It writes the test string to a file. If you want to write it to a printer or a control using their `Graphics` objects, you can do it the same way; just get/set the `dpi` before you calculate the first estimate of the height..

The code below creates this file; the  `Consolas` 'x' is 150 pixels tall as is the 2nd character (ox95) from the `Wingdings` font. (Note that I did not center the output):

[image: One inch X] [image]

```
// we are using these test data:
int Dpi = 150;
float targetHeight = 1.00f;
FontFamily ff = new FontFamily("Consolas");
int fs = (int) FontStyle.Regular;
string targetString = "X";

// this would be the height without the white space
int targetPixels = (int) targetHeight * Dpi;

// we write to a Btimpap. I make it large enough..
// Instead you can write to a printer or a Control surface..
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(targetPixels * 2, targetPixels * 2))
{
    // either set the resolution here
    // or get and use it above from the Graphics!
    bmp.SetResolution(Dpi, Dpi);
    using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        // good quality, please!
        G.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        G.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
        // target position (in pixels)
        PointF p0 = new PointF(0, 0);
        GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
        // first try:
        gp.AddString(targetString, ff, fs, targetPixels, p0,
                     StringFormat.GenericDefault);
        // this is the 1st result
        RectangleF gbBounds = gp.GetBounds();
        // now we correct the height:
        float tSize = targetPixels * targetPixels / gbBounds.Height;
        // and if needed the location:
        p0 = new PointF(p0.X  - gbBounds.X, p0.X - gbBounds.Y);
        // and retry
        gp.Reset();
        gp.AddString(targetString, ff, fs, tSize, p0, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
        // this should be good
        G.Clear(Color.White);
        G.FillPath(Brushes.Black, gp);
    }
    //now we save the image 
    bmp.Save("D:\\testString.png", ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

You may want to try using the correction factor to scale up a `Font` size and use `DrawString` after all.

There is also a way to calculate the numbers ahead using [`FontMetrics`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwf9s90b.aspx), but I understand the link to mean that such an approach could be font-dependent..

Comment: Thanks TaW.. Its Working Well.. But the Text is doesnt draw given place, if to draw different font with same position. How to solve this problem Mr. Taw

Comment: You are right; I had completely ignored the location but now I have added a line to calculate the corrected target position `p0`..

Comment: Thanks Taw.. Sorry for delay response.  Its more helpfully. Nice TaW