# WinForms: Drawing A Path In The Right Place

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphicspath

This is a follow-on to a question I asked here: [WinForms: Measure Text With No Padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51003124/winforms-measure-text-with-no-padding).  The question is, given this code ...

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        DrawIt(e.Graphics);
    }

    private void DrawIt(Graphics graphics) {
        var text = "123";
        var font = new Font("Arial", 72);
        // Build a path containing the text in the desired font, and get its bounds.
        GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
        path.AddString(text, font.FontFamily, (int)font.Style, font.Size, new Point(0, 0), StringFormat.GenericDefault);
        var bounds = path.GetBounds();
        // Find center of the form.
        var cx = this.ClientRectangle.Left + this.ClientRectangle.Width / 2;
        var cy = this.ClientRectangle.Top + this.ClientRectangle.Height / 2;
        // Move it where I want it.
        var xlate = new Matrix();
        xlate.Translate(cx - bounds.Width / 2, cy - bounds.Height / 2);
        path.Transform(xlate);
        // Draw the path (and a bounding rectangle).
        graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Black, path);
        bounds = path.GetBounds();
        graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, bounds.Left, bounds.Top, bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
        // This rectangle doesn't use the positioning from Translate but does use the same size.
        graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, cx - bounds.Width / 2, cy - bounds.Height / 2, bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
    }
```

... why don't the rectangles overlap?

[image]

Clearly, when I'm translating the path, I'm not translating by the same units that I'm later drawing them in, but I'm at a loss how to fix it.  Any ideas?

Comment: Looks pretty much like the padding you wanted to get rid of. Reza explains why..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a wrong assumption about `Bounds` of the path. Since you added the string to the path, starting from point `(0,0)`, you are assuming the location of the bounds of the path is `(0,0)`. That's not correct.

The following illustration shows the relation between the origin that you added string, `(0,0)` and bounds of the path, blue rectangle:

[image]

To fix it, after adding the string and getting its bounds, store the location of the bounds:

```
var p = bounds.Location;
```

And then after applying the transformations, draw the rectangle this way:

```
graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, 
     p.X + cx - bounds.Width / 2, p.Y + cy - bounds.Height / 2, 
     bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @Reza (and @TaW). Since what I wanted was to center the text at a specification location, I only needed to change  
`xlate.Translate(cx - bounds.Width / 2, cy - bounds.Height / 2);`  
... to ...  
`xlate.Translate(cx - bounds.Location.X - bounds.Width / 2, cy - bounds.Location.Y - bounds.Height / 2);`   ... and all is good. (A similar adjustment needs to be made to the blue box location, but it was only there to help me debug.)

Comment: Great. You're welcome. In fact the post tries to show the padding and let you draw the red rectangle in expected location. You know the fix you need.

Comment: How to do it with any rotation? Things get weird trying to compute the position for any angle. This transformation by moving the origin by GetBounds().Location works only with Rotation = 0

Comment: @user3625699 You need to calculate the offset and apply it to the matrix. You can see an example in here: [GraphicsPath text rendering issue (empty space between) - how to rotate around a point?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/939696/graphicspath-text-rendering-issue-empty-space-betw.html?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)